# Resuming file downloads in Ruby, range header issue

Tags: ruby, http-headers

When setting a range header in Ruby 1.8.7, an additional "X-REMOVED: Range" header is being added, which (seemingly) prevents download resumes from working.

```
size = File.size(local_file)
Net::HTTP.start(domain) do |http|
  headers = { 
    'Range' => "bytes=#{size}-"
  }
  resp = http.get(remote_file, headers)
  open(local_file, "wb") do |file|
    file.write(resp.body)
  end
end
```

Header sent:

```
GET /test.zip HTTP/1.1..Host: 192.168.50.1..Accept: */*..X-REMOVED: Range..Range: bytes=481-....
```

I've also tried using set_range with the same result.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. The resumes not working had nothing to do with the range header. It's just that I was opening the file with "wb" instead of "ab".

Comment: Consider answering your own question and marking it as the solution. You won't get any rep but it will let people see that this question was answered.

Comment: You could get a badge for it, though. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing. The resumes not working had nothing to do with the range header. It's just that I was opening the file with "wb" instead of "ab".