# What is X-REMOVED HTTP header?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, google-chrome

While trying to play with AJAX I tried to add "Range" header to the request. Sniffing with wireshark revealed the "X-Removed" header.

Couldn't find anything relevant on the web.
Does anyone knows what's this header?

[Testcase](http://jsfiddle.net/s9ZkW/) headers (using Chrome):

```
GET /img/initializing.png HTTP/1.1
Host: fiddle.jshell.net
Connection: keep-alive
X-REMOVED: Range
Accept: */*
Referer: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Range: bytes=0-
```

Comment: Related (not the solution, but regarding occurrence of that header): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464761/resuming-file-downloads-in-ruby-range-header-issue It's really silly, Google finds nothing but other mentions of the header. No documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Historically, designers and implementers of application protocols have often distinguished between standardized and unstandardized parameters by prefixing the names of unstandardized parameters with the string `"X-"` or similar constructs (e.g., "x."), where the "X" is commonly understood to stand for "eXperimental" or "eXtension".

Under this convention, the name of a parameter not only identified the data, but also embedded the status of the parameter into the name itself: a parameter defined in a specification produced by a recognized standards development organization (or registered according to processes defined in such a specification) did not start with `"X-"` or similar constructs, whereas a parameter defined outside such a specification or process started with `"X-"` or similar constructs.

`"X-"` headers are "non-standard headers" that is defined by the developer, and can mean anything they like it to mean, they don't really have to follow any standards as there is non.

However some `X-` headers are common, such as `X-Requested-With` which is sent with Ajax requests in all the widely used frameworks, like jQuery, and `X-Frame-Options` and `X-Powered-By` that is supported by most browsers, or the IE specific `X-UA-Compatible` but they are still not standardized headers.

In other words, any "X-" header is valid, and using the "X-" prefix means it's not a standard header, and it could do anything really.

Comment: Since Chrome sends it I would expect someone to know this header meaning. It's not a specific developer. I could say the same about header like x-forwarded-for which is non-standard header but everyone knows it's meaning

Comment: @Niros - Yes, but I could define my own header, and prefix it with X-, and it would be valid, but only I would know what it does. These are all non-standard headers, and some are commonly used and supported by most browsers, but there is no standard way to deal with such headers, it's up to the developer or the browser to decide what to do.

Comment: @adeneo It is all true - and it is not an answer to the question what that header does. I got interested - it is mentioned many times (googled) but nowhere is there an explanation. I don't know about you, I want to know stuff! This doesn't look like a "private" header of some kid, it seems to be in use out there not just on some obscure single random server. Well, at least that's what I got from a few minutes of "Google research" - but putting the question away like that seems unjustified to me.

Comment: @Mörre - It's definitively a Google header, and I tried searching without an answer as well, and the answer really is that these headers aren't defined anywhere, there's nowhere to look it up, so at the end of the day only Google really knows what it does, and it's probably something they use for something internally.

Comment: @adeneo On one of the pages I found someone claimed to have seen that header in an HTTP request started by .net (https://twitter.com/jpluscplusm/status/301685481102524416) but it's just a tweet...

Comment: Since there are comments about this from .NET, Ruby and javascript.. it would make a lot more sense to me that there's *something else* modifying this header. What if it's wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot verify your test case, since it throws a FileError before even attempting the XHR.

Just a hunch: disable all Chrome extensions you might have installed and try your test case again. This might be a case of an overzealous security / privacy / adblocking extension at work.

Comment: Looks like you are using Chrome private mode. Try with normal mode.
Anyway, even with no extensions I get the same results

Comment: I am not using Private Mode. Testcase on Chrome 32 / OS X exits with `FileError Code 3: An ongoing operation was aborted, typically with a call to abort()`.